# global name 'object_list' is not defined on django 1.6

Tags: python, django, listview

After updating Django from 1.4 to 1.6 I'm stuck with a `global name 'object_list' is not defined` problem

I have views.py:

```
def news(request, page):
    news = News.objects.filter(is_active=True).order_by('-timestamp')
    return object_list(
        request,
        page=page,
        queryset=news,
        paginate_by=3,
        template_object_name='news',
        template_name='blog-right-sidebar.html',
        extra_context={'current_page': 'news',
            'url_name': 'news', 'url_post_name': 'news_post'}
```

how to rewrite a code to use `ListView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView


class NewsView(ListView):
    paginate_by = 3
    template_name = 'blog-right-sidebar.html',
    context_object_name = 'news'
    queryset = News.objects.filter(is_active=True).order_by('-timestamp')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Here you can add any additional context items.
        context = super(NewsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['var'] = 'value'
        return context
```